# Using 'echo' for pre-selection not functioning as intended

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a profile settings page, pre-selecting the already-defined country. For some reason, though, my code isn't selecting anything at all.

(e.g. instead of `United States` being already selected, there's no selection at all.)

PHP:

```
function selectCountry($country) {
  if($_SESSION['user_country'] == $country) {
    echo ' selected';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<option value="United Kingdom" ' . selectCountry("United Kingdom") . '>United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States" ' . selectCountry("United States") . '>United States</option>
<option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands" ' . selectCountry("United States Minor Outlying Islands") . '>United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="Uruguay" ' . selectCountry("Uruguay") . '>Uruguay</option>
```

If I need to provide anything else, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `selectCountry` function should return a `String` instead of using `echo`. Return either `' selected'` or an empty string if it does not match.

Here's the syntax of the function that should work:

```
function selectCountry($country) {
    if($_SESSION['user_country'] == $country) {
        return ' selected';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Note that in PHP you don't define the types of variables or function return values.

Comment: Thanks so much @stvcisco! I'll try the code and then mark you as answer if it works. I come from Java, apologies for getting that mixed up. I appreciate it so much!